# Error: XMLHttpRequest error. Flutter in Http Package

Tags: flutter, dart, http, xmlhttprequest

When fetching anything from internet using http package it show error Error: XMLHttpRequest error. Flutter in Http Package Error in web only

```
var companyLogoResponse = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
      "https://stock.znindia.com/assets/assets/logo.png"),
);
var companyLogo = companyLogoResponse.bodyBytes;
```

> For Show image in PDF

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  child: Image(MemoryImage(companyLogo),
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
),
```

When Code Run it show

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10  createErrorWithStack
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 341:28            _throw
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 116:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1378:11                                          callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

Comment: this err is showing on flutter web. ?

Comment: yes only flutter web

Comment: Do u have control over backend files ?

Comment: Backend developed by php ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `cross-orgin` issue, If you have access over backend just add the below lines in your `api call`

```
headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
}
```

If the above method does not works try this library

```
flutter_cors: ^1.3.2
```

And finally a temporary solution

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

install this chrome extension